# creating alert buttons on click event for grid view in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

In My web application I am using grid view in index action  view. I need to create a  button called "book" which when clicks shows a dialog box  which displays the related content.
I tried this code but its not reacting to the event.
My code for index.php  grid view

```
<h1>Producer Offers</h1>

<?php 
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'columns'=>array(


                'offered_vegetable',
                'offered_qty',
                'unit_cost',
                'unit_delivery_cost',

                array(
                    'class'=>"bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn",
                        'deleteConfirmation'=>"js:'Do you really want to delete record with Offer name '+$(this).parent().parent().children(':nth-child(2)').text()+'?'",
                    'template'=>'{view}{book}{delete}',
                    'buttons' =>array(
                            'book'=>
                               array(
                               'label'=>'book',
                               'click' =>"js:alert('do u want to book this offer!')" 


                ),
        ),
                        ),
                ),

        )); 
?>
```

When the page is refreshed  it is displayed but I want to react to the event when the button is clicked, Anybody help me how to resolve this issue

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: no its not showing error in console

Comment: did you try with single quote instead of double quote?
 'class'=>"bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn",  and 'click' =>"js:alert('do u want to book this offer!')"

Comment: refer this forum: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/35038-yii-bootstrap-bootstrapwidgetstbgridview-dont-display-pagination/

Comment: you have to use `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: no it does not  make any difference

Comment: have you tried onclick instead?

Comment: ya tried its not working

Comment: Tried `'onclick' =>"alert(\"do u want to book this offer!\");" `??

Comment: Ya  i tried just now its not working

Comment: Umm, Sorry, but for last question :D have you tried `'book',array()` instead of `'book'=>array()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use **options** for that:

```
'book'=> array(
    'label'=>'book',
    'options' => array(  // set all kind of html options in here
        'onclick' =>"js:alert('do u want to book this offer!')",
         'style' => 'font-weight: bold',
    ),
 )
```